# SAP Adobe Forms Error: No Layout Exists in Original Language

Tags: adobe, abap

I am using TCode: SFP to create a Adobe Form

I am able to create a Form Interface and Form Context.

When I Check, Activate the form I get the error: No layout exists in original Language
Could Not Start Layout Designer.

Looks like I need to install Adobe Document Services and SAP Adobe LiveCycle Designer.

Where can i download these from and can I get a document that helps me installing these successfully.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm "see long text"?

Comment: Looks like Adobe Forms comes pre-installed on SAP on HANA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open Adobe Form, you need to install an extension. This can be downloaded from SAP's site, but you need to be an S-User to use it, otherwise you will not be allowed to open the page. Otherwise you need to install this extension:
Adobe LiveCycle Designer

Here you can find some info:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SUCCESSFACTORS_ONBOARDING/c94ed5fcb5fe4e0281f396556743812c/1b980168e59b4813b985fc302b2efe52.html

But you can download it from here:
https://me.sap.com/notes/2187332

Unfortunately, I don't know if it is available anywhere without SAP S-User.